# Creating a container from an iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a `set`, `list`, etc. from an iterator. Unfortunately, their constructors require an iterable rather than an iterator. I don't want to create an iterable that will be discarded shortly.

Of course, I could simply use list or set comprehension, which can do precisely what I want (and more). However, the syntax for them is idiosyncratic. So when I tried to write a function:

```
def create_from_gen(container_type, generator):
  return container_type(generator)
```

I got stuck. For user-defined containers, I can of course define my own constructors; for library and built-in types I have no choice. I could check for `list` and `set`, and use the special syntax I suppose, but that's ugly.

Comment: Can you give an example of the iterator you have?

Comment: Every iterator is  by definition iterable. Give a concrete example of the problem you have.

Comment: @NedBatchelder Sorry I was wrong... Apparently, all built-in types work fine with generators, just `numpy.array` doesn't. And that's just a problem specific to `numpy`. So my question is kinda pointless :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An iterator is also an iterable object. It should always have an `__iter__` method that returns itself. This is part of [the specification for iterators](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) in Python.

So just pass your iterator to the `list` or `set` constructor, and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

All iterators are iterable. The definition of "iterable" is that an iterator can be created from it.

```
>>> list(iter((1, 2, 3)))
[1, 2, 3]
```